# trying to call an other activity's method from asynctask

Tags: android, methods, android-asynctask

I have an async task that downloads a file from the web, it works fine when i preset the URL.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.mylocalweather.org.uk/ribblehead/clientraw.txt")
```

However when i try and use a method defined in an other activity to return a URL it fails.

```
URL url = null;
url = splash.gps();
```

The method has worked fine in the past and when called from other activities, and the download function works fine when the URL is hardcoded into the async therefore it much be a problem with calling the method from an Async task, whats the work around for this?

this is the error that it comes up with

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16426): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

Any help would be appreciated

many thanks

Comment: You might be better off running your GPS code in a service, not in the activity -- or if you do, then initiate the location acquisition on create, and fire off the async task once you get a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That other Activity doesn't exist (as the error notes, `onCreate` hasn't been called) and therefore can't use whatever system service you're using to get the URL.

Either have the AsyncTask retrieve the URL itself, or pass the information from the splash activity to the activity hosting the AsyncTask.

Comment: Passed the URL into the asynctask from the activity and it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as your Log says, you can't use a method of an `Activity` when that `Activity` was not created. Just use some of your classes and define your method there, passing it the parameters you need.

Comment: Actually, that's not what the log says. You could use any method of an activity, provided it's instantiated, at any time -- in that respect, it's just another class. However, the asker is probably using `getSystemService()`, and those calls are not available until after the activity was properly created.